# How can I get only the first line in a file that starts with "1." followed by any character except a number?

Tags: regex, awk, sed, grep

I have this file

```
1.1some text
2.some text
1.line I need
```

How can I print only the first line in a file that start with "1." followed by any character except a number?
I expect this:

```
1.line I need
```

my code is this

```
q=$(grep "^[0-9].[a-z]"  "file")
echo $q
```

Thank you

Comment: if only interested in lines that start with `1` why look for lines that start with *any* number (`[0-9]`)? an unescaped period (`.`) acts as a single-character wild card, to look for an explicit period you'll want to escape it (`\.`) or wrap in brackets (`[.]`)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With your shown samples, please try following `grep` code. Simple explanation would be: Using `grep`'s `m1` option to print only first match and exit from program then in main program mentioning regex to match lines that start from `1.` followed by a non-digit character, if match is found then print the line.

```
grep -m1 '^1\.[^0-9]'  Input_file
```

Answer (score 4):

> How can I print **only the first line** in a file that start with `1.`followed by any character **except a number**?

Using `sed`, you can use:

```sh
sed '/^1\.[^0-9]/!d;q' file

1.line I need
```

**Details:**

- `-n`: Suppresses regular output
- `/^1\.[^0-9]/`: Search for a line starting with `1` followed by a dot and a non-digit
- `!d`: Deletes all non-matching lines
- `q`: Quits further processing

---

Similar solution in `awk` would be:

```sh
awk '/^1\.[^0-9]/{print; exit}' file
```